# How to do v-for in intervals when using quasar carousel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

I am creating a small blog summary page that has 3 blog posts per slide in a q-carousel. The pagination component shifts to the next slide. I am not sure how to make this more dynamic so I can list all the blog posts in one array and then v-for through it and dynamically create the 3 blog posts per slide but also have the pagination linked.

So realistically I only want to have to update that array by adding items to it for each blog post and not have to mess with the template further. Any ideas how to do groupings like this?

My code is as follows:

```
<template>
  <div class="skew-cc"></div>
  <div class="tw-bg-white tw-py-24 sm:tw-py-32">
    <div class="tw-mx-auto tw-max-w-7xl tw-px-6 lg:tw-px-8">
      <div class="service-block q-pa-lg text-center column no-wrap flex-center block-wrapper" id="Blog">
        <h2 class="text-h2 text-weight-bolder text-dark q-mb-xs">Useful Articles</h2>
        <h6 class="text-h6 text-weight-light text-dark q-my-none" style="max-width: 800px;">We hope to share some of our knowledge to help you make an informed decision!</h6>
      </div>
        <q-carousel
          v-model="slide"
          transition-prev="slide-right"
          transition-next="slide-left"
          animated
          control-color="primary"
          class="full-height full-width"
        >
          <q-carousel-slide name="1" class="column no-wrap flex-center">
            <div class="tw-mx-auto tw-mt-16 tw-grid tw-max-w-2xl tw-grid-cols-1 tw-gap-x-8 tw-gap-y-20 lg:tw-mx-0 lg:tw-max-w-none lg:tw-grid-cols-3">
              <article v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" class="tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-items-start tw-justify-between">
                <div class="tw-relative tw-w-full">
                  <q-img :src="post.imageUrl" alt="" class="aspect-[16/9] w-full rounded-2xl bg-gray-100 object-cover sm:aspect-[2/1] lg:aspect-[3/2]" />
                  <div class="absolute inset-0 rounded-2xl ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-900/10" />
                </div>
                <div class="tw-max-w-xl">
                  <div class="tw-mt-8 tw-flex tw-items-center tw-gap-x-4 tw-text-xs">
                    <time :datetime="post.datetime" class="tw-text-gray-500">{{ post.date }}</time>
                    <a :href="post.category.href" class="tw-relative tw-z-10 tw-rounded-full tw-bg-gray-50 tw-px-3 tw-py-1.5 tw-font-medium tw-text-gray-600 hover:tw-bg-gray-100">{{ post.category.title }}</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tw-group tw-relative">
                    <h3 class="tw-mt-3 tw-text-lg tw-font-semibold tw-leading-6 tw-text-gray-900 group-hover:tw-text-gray-600">
                      <a :href="post.href">
                        <span class="tw-absolute tw-inset-0" />
                        {{ post.title }}
                      </a>
                    </h3>
                    <p class="tw-mt-5 tw-line-clamp-3 tw-text-sm tw-leading-6 tw-text-gray-600">{{ post.description }}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tw-relative tw-mt-8 tw-flex tw-items-center tw-gap-x-4">
                    <img :src="post.author.imageUrl" alt="" class="tw-h-10 tw-w-10 tw-rounded-full tw-bg-gray-100" />
                    <div class="tw-text-sm tw-leading-6">
                      <p class="tw-font-semibold tw-text-gray-900">
                        <a :href="post.author.href">
                          <span class="tw-absolute tw-inset-0" />
                          {{ post.author.name }}
                        </a>
                      </p>
                      <p class="tw-text-gray-600">{{ post.author.role }}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </q-carousel-slide>
        </q-carousel>
      
      <div class="q-pa-lg q-mt-xl flex flex-center">
        <q-pagination
          v-model="currentPage"
          :max="2"
          direction-links
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref , watch} from 'vue'

  const currentPage = ref(1);
  const slide = ref('1');
  const posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Common Electrical Problems In Your Home that You Should Leave it to the Professionals',
    href: '#',
    description:
      "Electricity is the jolt that keeps everything buzzing. In the electrifying world of homeownership, dealing with electrical issues can be a wild experience. Wires snaking through walls, charges ready to zap, and the fear of being plunged into darkness – it's enough to make your hair stand on end! But fear not, for you're not alone. We're here to shed some light on them.",
    imageUrl: '../assets/imgs/blog/post 1.jpg',
    date: 'July 5, 2023',
    datetime: '2023-07-05',
    category: { title: 'Electrical Repair', href: '#' },
    author: {
      name: 'Bill Griffin',
      role: 'Owner / Master Electrician',
      href: '#',
      imageUrl:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519244703995-f4e0f30006d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: '6 Shockingly Good Reasons to Upgrade AFCI and GFCI Circuit Breakers',
    href: '#',
    description:
      "Circuit breakers prevent electrical fires and protect individuals from electric shocks. While GFCIs circuit breakers protect against shocking encounters, AFCI circuit breakers put on their fire hats to extinguish potential blazes. The moment they sense a ground fault, they hit the brakes on the electrical flow, keeping you safe from harm. It's a dynamic duo working together to keep your home safe and sound.",
    imageUrl: '../assets/imgs/blog/post 2.jpeg',
    date: 'July 7, 2023',
    datetime: '2023-07-07',
    category: { title: 'Electrical Upgrades', href: '#' },
    author: {
      name: 'Bill Griffin',
      role: 'Owner / Master Electrician',
      href: '#',
      imageUrl:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519244703995-f4e0f30006d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Why Everyone Needs A Generator Backup Hookup for Continuous Power Supply',
    href: '#',
    description:
      "Power outages can disrupt our lives in numerous ways, causing inconvenience and potentially hazardous situations. In Harford County, Maryland, where severe weather events are uncommon, a generator backup hookup can be a game-changer. Last year, Harford County experienced 12,370 outages with BGE and 36 outages with Delmarva Power. By investing in a generator hookup, Harford County residents can protect themselves and their properties from the consequences of weather-related power outages. In this blog post, we will see the worst-case scenarios of losing power, discuss what a generator backup hookup is, how to connect it and shed light on the prevalence of weather-related power outages in Harford County.",
    imageUrl: '../assets/imgs/blog/post 3.jpeg',
    date: 'July 9, 2023',
    datetime: '2023-07-09',
    category: { title: 'Electrical Upgrades', href: '#' },
    author: {
      name: 'Chris Whiteford',
      role: 'Owner / Master Electrician',
      href: '#',
      imageUrl:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519244703995-f4e0f30006d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',
    },
  },
]

watch(currentPage, (currentValue, oldValue) => {
      slide.value = currentValue.toString();
    });

</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .block-wrapper{
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .block-wrapper-xl{
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  /*dividor code for mini t shirt*/
  .divider {
    /* minor cosmetics */
    display: table;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%; /* divider width */
    margin: 10px auto 40px; /* spacing above/below */
  }
  .divider span {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
  }
  .divider span:first-child,
  .divider span:last-child {
    width: 50%;
    top: 13px; /* adjust vertical align */
    -moz-background-size: 100% 2px; /* line width */
    background-size: 100% 2px; /* line width */
    background-position: 0 0, 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  .divider span:first-child {
    /* color changes in here */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      0 0,
      0 100%,
      from(transparent),
      to(#000)
    );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, $dark);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, $dark);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, $dark);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, $dark);
  }
  .divider span:nth-child(2) {
    color: $dark;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .divider span:last-child {
    /* color changes in here */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      0 0,
      0 100%,
      from($dark),
      to(transparent)
    );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, $dark, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, $dark, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, $dark, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $dark, transparent);
  }

  /*diagonal dividor markup*/
  .colour-block {
    background:#F5F5F5;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:100px;
    color:#fff;
  }
  .white-block {
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:100px;
    color:#F5F5F5;
  }
  /*------------------*/
  /*  SKEW CLOCKWISE  */
  /*------------------*/
  .skew-cc{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #F5F5F5 49%, #fff 50%),    linear-gradient(-50deg, #ffffff 16px, #000 0);
  }

  /*-------------------------*/
  /* SKEW COUNTER CLOCKWISE  */
  /*-------------------------*/
  .skew-c{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #fff 49%, #F5F5F5 50%);
  }

.blog-blurb{
  line-height: 2;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround

```
<q-carousel
            v-else
            v-model="carouselIndex"
            transition-prev="slide-right"
            transition-next="slide-left"
            swipeable
            animated
            navigation
            padding
            control-color="primary"
            infinite
            arrows
            class="transparent full-height"
            keep-alive
        >
            <q-carousel-slide
                v-for="(entity, index) in entities" 
                :key="index"  
                :name="index"
            >
                <div class="row justify-center">

                    <!-- Before Current -->  
                    <EntityIndex
                        class="result-width q-ma-sm"
                        v-if="entities.length > 1"
                        :entity="index === 0 ? entities[entities.length - 1] : entities[index - 1]" 
                        @load="setPopupEntity(index === 0 ? entities.length - 1 : index - 1)"
                    />
                    <!-- Current -->  
                    <EntityIndex
                        class="result-width q-ma-sm"
                        :entity="entities[index]" 
                        @load="setPopupEntity(index)"
                    />
                    <!-- After Current -->  
                    <EntityIndex
                        class="result-width q-ma-sm"
                        v-if="entities.length > 2"
                        :entity="index === entities.length - 1 ? entities[0] : entities[index + 1]" 
                        @load="setPopupEntity(index === entities.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1)"
                    />
                </div>
            </q-carousel-slide>
        </q-carousel>
```